# AddWithValue-method (C#) does nothing

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm currently writing a class to handle all database-activity in my application, and so I've come to the method that performs UPDATE-queries.

As of now I'm returning and displaying the content of the commandtext to check it, and it seems fine:

```
UPDATE news SET title = @title, newsContent = @newsContent, excerpt = @excerpt, date = @date, urlTitle = @urlTitle, isPublished = @isPublished WHERE (id = @id);
```

So, fine in other words. The next step is to replace all @values with actual values - and this is where i hit problems. Nothing happens. The AddWithValue-method just doesn't seem to do anything, and i find no reason for this.

```
public string updateQuery(string table, string[] fields, object[] values, string conditionField, object conditionValue)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder("UPDATE " + table + " SET ");

        int i = 1;
        foreach (string s in fields)
        {
            if (i == fields.Length)
            {
                cmd.Append(s + " = @" + s + " ");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Append(s + " = @" + s + ", ");
            }

            i++;
        }

        cmd.Append("WHERE (" + conditionField + " = @" + conditionField + ");");
        command.CommandText = cmd.ToString();

        int j = 0;
        foreach (object o in values)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + fields[j], o);
            j++;
        }
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + conditionField, conditionValue);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        return command.CommandText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: What happens when you look at the database profiler to see what has been sent up?

Comment: Where does the command object come from?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Try to create a new SqlCommand and add the properties to that. Apart from that it must be that the values array contains null values

Comment: The command-object is part of the class, and works perfectly fine in several other methods, so i see no reason for it not to work here.

Jon Skeet: Database-profiler? :S
Have i missed something? Is there an easy way to see exactly what's being picked up by the database?

Comment: So what happens when the command is executed? Do you get an exception? What is it? Or does nothing get updated? Can you try narrowing down the problem to see if it's just the where clause?

Comment: I get no exception, and nothing is updated.

The weird thing is, i've used the exact same way of doing everything as in another method i've written which works. Only difference is that this is an update-query, and the other one is an insert-query.

Comment: And I've also tried hard-coding in a value in the where clause with no luck.

Comment: What does ExecuteNonQuery() return? That'll tell you how many rows were affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions Joel Coehoorn, i will look into them.

Still, i want to get my stuff to work :p

Just noticed that the date-field actually have been updating itself all the time. None of the other fields, though. This just makes less sense the more i look at it. Maybe its better to try in the morning than at midnight.

EDIT:
Found out what the problem was, and it was far simpler than i expected. I'd forgotten to check if the page was a postback, so every time i updated the database, the fields were filled with data FROM the database before the submit-method was called. So, the update-method worked all along. *blush*

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "it doesn't do anything"? Do you mean that the parameters don't have values when the command is executed? Or that the command text stays the same?

If it's the latter then this is expected. The command doesn't change the query text, it sends the query text as is, along with the parameter values, to the server.

Comment: Ah, I didnt know the text stayed the same, so i guess that's not the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible thatthe arg-value is null? If so the param won't be added. For nulls, you need to use `DBNull.Value`; for example (not the only way to do it):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(argName, (object)argValue ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: (note of course that = won't return a match on NULL under ANSI-standard TSQL, so you might have to do more work in this case, perhaps with ISNULL/NULLIF)

Comment: Marc Gravell: Nope, there are no null-values. Checked and double-checked :)

Answer (score 1):

Potentially the value of ID you are supplying doesn't match an entry in the table you are updating.

BTW drop the try..catch it isn't serving any purpose.

Comment: The try catch is worse than serving no purpose, it's losing the stack trace as well.

Comment: and what's with the looping? Am I the only one who would very much prefer for(int j =0; j < values.Length; j++)<br>
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + fields[j], o[j]);

Comment: ah, the perils of posting code on the internet, everyone will try and improve it. (not that I don't agree with Kevin).

Comment: The ID supplied does match an entry in the table. Try/catch removed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting the string to be updated, you will be disappointed.  A big feature of using a parameterized query is that values are never substituted directly into the command string, and thus you are protected from that kind of security vulnerability.  Instead, the data is transmitted to the server separately.

Let me suggest this new function signature:

```
public string updateQuery(string table, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> values, KeyValuePair<string, object> condition)
```

This will create a strong association between your parameter names and the values, and also give you the flexibility to use constructs other than an array (though an array would certainly also be accepted).  Then the code would look like this:

```
public string updateQuery(string table, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> values, KeyValuePair<string, object> condition)
{
    using (StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder("UPDATE [" + table + "]\nSET "))
    {
        string delimiter = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in values)
        {
           cmd.AppendFormat("{0}[{1}]=@{1}", delimiter, item.Key);
           delimiter = ",\n";
        }
        cmd.AppendFormat("\nWHERE [{0}]= @{0};", condition.Key);

        command.CommandText = cmd.ToString();
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in values)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Key, (object)item.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
    }
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + condition.Key, condition.Value);

    // you didn't show where the connection was created or opened
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    connection.Close();

    return command.CommandText;
}
```

Even better if you can use something that would create strongly-typed database parameters (like `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>`, for example).

Comment: I'll check that out.

Anyways, the connection is opened when an instance of the class is created. Working just fine, several other methods using it already.

Comment: Then you probably don't want to close it here, otherwise it's broken when you use the same class instance for two operations.

Comment: Instead, remove the connection.Close(), but have your class also implement IDisposable and close it there.

Comment: Finally, be very careful not to let instances hang around longer than necessary: database connections are a scarce resource.

Comment: Yep, i know. That part should be fine though, I usually only perform one operation on the database at a time. All of this is part of a fairly simple CMS for a website.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post the rest of the code involved as well, i guess. First the method that passes on the values:

```
public void updatePost(int postId)
{
    DbConnection d = new DbConnection();

    string[] fields = {
                          "title",
                          "newsContent",
                          "excerpt",
                          "date",
                          "urlTitle",
                          "isPublished" 
                      };

    object[] values = {
                          this.title,
                          this.content,
                          this.excerpt,
                          this.date,
                          this.urlTitle,
                          this.isPublished,
                      };

    d.updateQuery("news",fields,values,"id",postId);
}
```

Constructor method that connects to the database:

```
public DbConnection()
{        
    connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****; User Id=****; Password=*****;");
    connection.Open();
    command = connection.CreateCommand();
}
```

I've yet to find out the problem, but I do really appreciate all help i get anyways. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using my other code, your new updatePost method would look like this.

```
using DBParam = KeyValuePair<string, object>; // reduce need to keep re-typing this

public void updatePost(int postId)
{   
    List<DBParam> values = new List<DBParam>();

    values.Add(new DBParam("title", this.title));
    values.Add(new DBParam("newsContent", this.content));
    values.Add(new DBParam("excerpt", this.excerpt));
    values.Add(new DBParam("date", this.date));
    values.Add(new DBParam("urlTitle", this.urlTitle));
    values.Add(new DBParam("isPublished", this.isPublished));

    new DbConnection().updateQuery("news", values, new DBParam("id", postid));
}
```